# Regex - Replacing part of a number string

Tags: regex

I have the following scenario:

```
string source1 "ABC?XYZ";
string source2 "DEF?PQR";
string replacement = "123"
string result = Regex.Replace(source1, @"([A-Z]{3,})(\?+)([A-Z]{3,})", "$1" + replacement + "$3");
```

The problem is of course, that the replacement string expands to "S1123$3" which confuses the parser as it tries to find $1123.

Can anyone tell me how the elements can be delimited from the replacement string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you concatenate `"$1" + replacement + "$3"`, it gives "$1123$3". The regex parser will try to replace the 1123rd capturing group, thus it won't do anything.

If the conventions of PHP are valid in the language you code (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)), you can accomplish what you want by changing the `$n` replacement references to `${n}`, like this :

```
string result = 
  Regex.Replace( source1, @"([A-Z]{3,})(\?+)([A-Z]{3,})",
                 "${1}" + replacement + "${3}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `${n}` instead of `$n`, i.e. `${1}` and `${3}` in your example:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(source1, @"([A-Z]{3,})(\?+)([A-Z]{3,})", "${1}" + replacement + "${3}");
```